# Selectively reading in csv files in R where filenames don't end in a particular suffix

Tags: r, regex, csv, filenames

I have a folder of csv files from an experiment that I want to read into R for analysis. The folder contains two files for every participant, with filenames following the pattern:

```
"participantID.csv"
"participantID_debrief.csv"
```

I want to create two variables in R, one for the standard data files and one for the debrief files. I have found the list.files function and see that the standard way to use this would be like:

```
files <- list.files(path="D:/data", pattern=".csv")
```

But I want to use the pattern parameter to match first only the filenames that **don't** end in "_debrief.csv" and then only the ones that **do**. How would I write the regular expression (assuming that's what pattern is) to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
files = list.files(path="D:/data")
non_debrief = files[!grepl("_debrief.csv", files)]
debrief = files[grepl("_debrief.csv", files)]
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work - I get all the filenames in non_debrief and debrief is empty. However, I did manage to use this as a template to work out the following solution: 

`all_files <- list.files(path="./pilot_1")`
`data_files <- all_files[!grepl("_debrief.csv", all_files)]`
`debrief_files <- all_files[grepl("_debrief.csv", all_files)]` 

So thanks!

Comment: Ah ok - can you see the edit and if that works?

Comment: Yep, I think that's the same logic as what I had in the comment above. Thanks very much - grepl was what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

For a tidyverse approach, you could use the fs library (https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2018/01/fs-1.0.0/).

```
base_dir = 'D:/data/'
file_list_debrief = fs::dir_ls(base_dir, glob = '*_debrief.csv$')
file_list_non_debrief = fs::dir_ls(base_dir, glob = '*_debrief.csv$', invert = TRUE)
```

Comment: I actually love this, thank you, I learned something new!